# Google Visualization - Can Bubble Chart and Candlestick Chart Use Same Data Source?

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a dashboard that has a bubble chart and a candlestick chart.  The bubble chart shows bubble chart shows student test scores from last year (x-axis) to this year (y-axis) and the size of the bubble is proportional to the number of students.  I would also like to create a candlestick chart that shows the interquartile range (to convey the distribution).

I get my dataset by using:

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('mysource');

query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K');

query.send(function (response) {        
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();
```

The Bubble Chart gets its data from the first 5 columns ([as detailed here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart)).  And it seems that the Candlestick Chart also gets its data from the first 6 columns ([as detailed here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart)).  However, I need my Candlestick Chart to pull from the columns F to K.  Is that possible?

I am trying to make a dashboard where the controls filter what is shown on the Bubble Chart AND on the Candlestick Chart...so I assume that I need to use the same data source.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same data source for both, but you need to separate out the columns you need for each chart using either a DataView or the ChartWrapper's `view` parameter.  I'm assuming that you are using ChartWrappers, since they are required to link charts to controls in a Dashboard.  This is how you would use the view parameter:

```
var bubbleChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    // set ChartWrapper parameters
    chartType: 'BubbleChart',
    containerId: '...',
    options: {...},
    view: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] // use columns A-E
    }
});
var candlestickChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    // set ChartWrapper parameters
    chartType: 'CandlestickChart',
    containerId: '...',
    options: {...},
    view: {
        columns: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // use columns F-K
    }
});
```